# Unable to renew a Certbot NGINX certificate

Tags: nginx, debian, ssl-certificate, lets-encrypt, certbot

I have a NGINX server and I use Certbot to generate a Let's Encrypt certificate. I saw that my certificate was not renewing automatically despite the cron I had set up.
I tried to renew it manually with the command:

```
$ certbot renew --cert-name pbx.info.eu --nginx
Could not choose appropriate plugin: The manual plugin is not working; there may be problems with your existing configuration. The error was: PluginError('An authentication script must be provided with --manual-auth-hook when using the manual plugin non-interactively.'). 
The requested nginx plugin does not appear to be installed certbot.
```

So I did this command:

```
$ sudo apt install python3-certbot-nginx  
E: The package "python3-certbot-nginx" has no version that can be installed
```

I am on **Debian 10** and the version of certbot is **0.31.0**

When I run certbot renew I always get the same error message

```
$ certbot renew
Saving debug log to /var/log/letsencrypt/letsencrypt.log

- - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - -
Processing /etc/letsencrypt/renewal/pbx.info.eu
- - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - -
Cert is due for renewal, auto-renewing...
Could not choose appropriate plugin: The manual plugin is not working; there may be problems with your existing configuration.
The error was: PluginError('An authentication script must be provided with --manual-auth-hook when using the manual plugin non-interactively.')
Attempting to renew cert (pbx.info.eu) from /etc/letsencrypt/renewal/pbx.info.eu produced an unexpected error: The manual plugin is not working; there may be problems with your existing configuration.
The error was: PluginError('An authentication script must be provided with --manual-auth-hook when using the manual plugin non-interactively.'). Skipping.
All renewal attempts failed. The following certs could not be renewed:
  /etc/letsencrypt/live/pbx.info.eu/fullchain.pem (failure)

- - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - -

All renewal attempts failed. The following certs could not be renewed:
  /etc/letsencrypt/live/pbx.info.eu/fullchain.pem (failure)
- - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - -
1 renew failure(s), 0 parse failure(s)
```

Here are the contents of `/etc/letsencrypt/renewal/pbx.info.eu.conf`

```
$ cat /etc/letsencrypt/renewal/pbx.info.eu.conf
# renew_before_expiry = 30 days
version = 0.31.0
archive_dir = /etc/letsencrypt/archive/pbx.info.eu
cert = /etc/letsencrypt/live/pbx.info.eu/cert.pem
privkey = /etc/letsencrypt/live/pbx.info.eu/privkey.pem
chain = /etc/letsencrypt/live/pbx.info.eu/chain.pem
fullchain = /etc/letsencrypt/live/pbx.info.eu/fullchain.pem

# Options used in the renewal process
[renewalparams]
account = 
pref_challs = dns-01,
authenticator = manual
manual_public_ip_logging_ok = True
server = https://acme-v02.api.letsencrypt.org/directory
```

Comment: You generally don't need any additional parameters for renew. Try just `certbot renew`; will it help? Also, please, [post](https://serverfault.com/posts/1100639/edit) what's in the `/etc/letsencrypt/renewal/[certname].conf`, but *mask sensitive details like account ID*.

Comment: When I do `certbot renew`I have already the error message @NikitaKipriyanov

Answer (score 1):

This configuration looks like you obtained this certificate first using DNS-01 challenge. Were you doing it by hand (Errm, what's the point, the Let's Encrypt is all about automation)?

Anyway, if you don't need features that are only available using DNS-01 challenge (e.g. wildcard certificates), you can revert to HTTP-01 challenge. To do that, remove all references to this certificate and request new certificate with the same name. This time, make sure you are using Nginx plugins, both "authenticator" and "installer". This is what [suggested on the Let's Encrypt forum](https://community.letsencrypt.org/t/how-to-change-certbot-verification-method/56735).

Or you can [try to set the preferred challenge](https://community.letsencrypt.org/t/changing-authenticator-from-manual-to-nginx/114830/3): `certbot renew --preferred-challenges http --nginx [domain]`. Do this once, it should record that into renewal file and then follow-up renewals will work with just "certbot renew". This looks exactly like your case.